# Sending data in 3-byte packet

Tags: visual-c++, arrays

I am trying to send a command to my LAC board using visual c++. On page 6 of [LAC Config](http://www.firgelli.com/Uploads/LAC_Advanced_Configuration.pdf) it says that the Buffer is sent in a 3-byte packet.

```
Buffer[0]=Control

Buffer[1]=Data Low

Buffer[2]=Data High
```

What does this mean and how do I figure out what I should set each of these values to?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read on, you will see that next comes a list of all control-codes, followed by a detailed description of each of them. The manual also mentions that sample-code is available, probably somewhere on their website.

In general, setting the values is a bit tricky. `BYTE` is probably a typedef or macro that resolves to an unsigned 8-bit data-type, meaning it can only hold values from 0 to 255. Two bytes could represent values up to 65535. However, if you want to store a value greater than 255 if that buffer, you'd have to decompose it into its higher and lower byte. You can do this the following way:

```
unsigned int value = 512;
BYTE low_byte = 0xff & value;
BYTE high_byte = value >> 8;
```

Comment: yea I see the control codes. Would I be setting the buffer[0] to the control code and would I be doing something like Buffer[0]= 0x03 or Buffer[0]=SET_ACCURACY? What would the other two buffer values be set to? The sample code they have is LabView code while I am using Visual C++... I called and they said they had no C++ examples...

Comment: @moesef: THis means that the control code `SET_ACCURRACY` is represented by the value `1` (`0x01` is just hex for `1`). And yes, that goes into `buffer[0]`. The data-part is specific for each command, as explained in the manual.

Comment: so for example, if I wanted to the Linear Actuator to extend halfway as in the example they give in the manual. I would set `Buffer[0]=0x20; Buffer[1]=512; Buffer[2]=512;`? Although, if `BYTE Buffer[3]` then the int would be converted into a byte correct? Is this what I want? Thanks for the help BTW.

Comment: @mosef: I updated my answer with some practical tips. Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: thanks! I will read/interpret this and give you some feedback but it already looks to be pretty helpful.

Comment: @moesef: I removed a large of my answer, because it was incorrect, I will get back to this though.

Comment: what you posted worked out perfectly with the LAC board. Thanks!